# Eliminating empty space with hidden html in CSS

Tags: html, css, mpmediaquery

I am trying to hide certain content with visibility based on media query. It works, but it creates empty scrollable space like the containers are still there.  Is there a way to eliminate this?

When the screen is in "Desktop" mode - it has all the mobile empty space below and vice versa when in "Mobile".

http://oberers.com/mt2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change div.desktop

```
visibility: hidden
```

to

```
display: none
```

Reference: [display none](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)